# Can modal operator be defined as a boolean function?

Tags: math, operators, artificial-intelligence, modal-logic

Let us consider for simplicity only Kripke structures with a single agent whose knowledge is described by the modal operator K. We know that in all the corresponding Kripke  structures where K is interpreted by equivalence there holds for any formula A

a) the formula KA -> A (Knowledge Axiom) is valid ,
 b)  but the formulas A -> KA and ¬KA are not valid.

Utilize these facts to show that such a behaviour of the modal operator K cannot be encoded by any boolean function (ie. Truth values defined by a table).

**Hint**: Suppose the truth value of KA can be calculated from the truth value of A using a truth table for K (in the same way as ¬A is calculated form A). Consider all possible truth tables for K and show that none of them grants the properties a) and b) mentioned above.

I dont understand that hint... making truth table of K is like constructing truth table of negation symbol ¬ , which in my mind doesnt make sense I think it makes sense only to make negation of something and not just negation

Comment: It's quite common to say "truth table of _some logical operation_" as a short-hand for "truth table of the formula applying _some logical operation_ to variables". So the truth table of ¬ is the truth table of ¬p,  the truth table of & is the truth table of p & q, etc.

Comment: thank you, that means this problem is quite easy... for A i have T or F and then I just need to make all possible truth tables for KA ( T T, T F, F T , F F) and evaluate those formulas and I will see that if we were trying encode K as boolean function sometimes KA -> A would be False and not always b) properties would be False

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't directly about programming. (It would have been a good fit on either [philosophy.se] or [math.se].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider all possible truth tables for K:

```
| A | K₁A | K₂A  | K₃A | K₄A |
—————————————————————————————
| 1 |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
—————————————————————————————
| 0 |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
```

> Show that none of them grants the properties a) and b) mentioned above.

**Case 1**

```
| A | KA  | KA->A | A->KA | ¬KA |
—————————————————————————————————
| 1 |  1  |   1   |   1   |  0  |
—————————————————————————————————
| 0 |  1  |   0   |   1   |  0  |
```

In this case, `KA->A` is not a tautology.

**Case 2**

```
| A | KA  | KA->A | A->KA | ¬KA |
—————————————————————————————————
| 1 |  1  |   1   |   1   |  0  |
—————————————————————————————————
| 0 |  0  |   1   |   1   |  1  |
```

In this case, `A->KA` is a tautology.

**Case 3**

```
| A | KA  | KA->A | A->KA | ¬KA |
—————————————————————————————————
| 1 |  0  |   1   |   0   |  1  |
—————————————————————————————————
| 0 |  1  |   0   |   1   |  0  |
```

In this case, `KA->A` is not a tautology.

**Case 4**

```
| A | KA  | KA->A | A->KA | ¬KA |
—————————————————————————————————
| 1 |  0  |   1   |   0   |  1  |
—————————————————————————————————
| 0 |  0  |   1   |   1   |  1  |
```

In this case, `¬KA` is a tautology.

---

Can desired behaviour of `K` be encoded by many-valued matrix?

For alethic modal systems, the answer is the following:

- 3 values are insufficient,
- 4 values are sufficient for the so-called basic modal logic,
- any finite number of values is insufficient for syntactically “full” and deductively “natural” modal system.

See, e. g., introductory parts in [the article](http://www.jyb-logic.org/papers/02beziau-galley-proofs.pdf) by Jean-Yves Beseau.
I hope these results are relevant for epistemic modal systems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had this same idea I was just confused a little bit if this is what the problem was about.